# How to remotely execute and debug a process at its startup?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I can setup my local machine such that upon execution of a particular application, I can start the debugger.  Is this possible to do this for a remote application?

This is a batch file that I use to invoke the debugger locally upon execution of `app.exe`:

```
@echo off
 >%temp%\output.reg echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>>%temp%\output.reg echo+
>>%temp%\output.reg echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\app.exe]
>>%temp%\output.reg echo "debugger"="vsjitdebugger.exe"
regedit /s %temp%\output.reg
del %temp\output.reg
```

For completeness, here is the batch file I use to stop the debugger from being invoked on startup:

```
@echo off
 >%temp%\output.reg echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>>%temp%\output.reg echo+
>>%temp%\output.reg echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\app.exe]
>>%temp%\output.reg echo "debugger"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" /debugexe"
regedit /s %temp%\output.reg
del %temp\output.reg
```

Maybe there's a way to modify this so that the process will cause something like an assertion message and then I can attach my debugger remotely at that point?

Alternatively, is it possible for the debugger to inject the application to the remote system and have it start up in debug mode like when I just start the debug process locally?

Comment: It helps when your question actually explains the problem you're trying to solve. Your edit makes it clear now what you're asking.

Comment: Writing a question can be an iterative process.